# Unlock Verizon 4S iPhone

Tags: iphone, unlock

I just purchased used iPhone 4S from a Verizon customer in the United States. I would like to unlock it and take it to Europe and use it on a GSM network. How can I do this?

Phone info:

- iPhone 4S
- iOS 7.0.2
- Baseband 5.0.0

Are any of these factory IMEI unlock services good? Has anyone tried it?

http://www.officialiphoneunlock.co.uk/

http://unlockiphonevip.com/

http://www.yourappleiphone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Verizon will unlock the phone for global use only, provided you've been a customer in good standing for at least 60 days. Otherwise, they will refuse to unlock it, and under no circumstances will they unlock it for domestic use.

Alternatively, you may find unlocking services on eBay, but these aren't as popular for Verizon phones as they are for AT&T.

There are no "Ultrasn0w"-type software unlocks anymore, so going through official channels is the only option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Verizon might unlock this for free. But they denied it even though I have an account with them. So my last hope, but it went through was the site for 3rd party unlocking http://www.flyunlock.com/verizon-usa

Mine was iPhone 4S